# Can not understand leak canary notification when doing transition animation

Tags: android, leakcanary

I am facing `OutOfMemoryException` as a result I have installed **Square's Leak Canary** to understand where the leak is. I am using shared element transitions.

```
 ┬
├─ android.widget.Toast$TN
│    Leaking: NO (it's a GC root and Toast.TN (Transient Notification) is never leaking)
│    ↓ Toast$TN.mNextView
├─ android.widget.FrameLayout
│    Leaking: NO (MainActivity↓ is not leaking and View attached)
│    View#mAttachInfo is not null (view attached)
│    View#mParent is set
│    View.mID=-1 (name not found)
│    View.mWindowAttachCount=1
│    ↓ FrameLayout.mContext
├─ com.rj.app.MainActivity
│    Leaking: NO (MainActivity#mDestroyed is false)
│    ↓ MainActivity.mActivityTransitionState
│                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
├─ android.app.ActivityTransitionState
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ ActivityTransitionState.mEnterTransitionCoordinator
│                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
├─ android.app.EnterTransitionCoordinator
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ EnterTransitionCoordinator.mTransitioningViews
│                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
├─ java.util.ArrayList
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ ArrayList.elementData
│                ~~~~~~~~~~~
├─ java.lang.Object[]
│    Leaking: UNKNOWN
│    ↓ array Object[].[3]
│                     ~~~
╰→ androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
​     Leaking: YES (RefWatcher was watching this)
, retainedHeapSize=null)])
```

I have received the notification like above, but since I am new at it I am unable to understand what is happening, can someone elaborate it for me?